# Concatenate 2 columns in one column "title" on a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, concatenation, sharepoint-online

I would like to concatenate 2 columns in one column on a sharepoint list, but this is the TITLE column which is a single text column.

How can i do that ?

In fact i would like to concatenate a column ID (The ID column) and a column CODE POSTAL OF A CITY ( A calculated column) in an only column which is the column TITLE ( Single line of text Column) of my Sharepoint's list.

I have some ideas for formules and i have tried it :

***=CONCATENER([ID];"-";[Code INSEE de la commune])***

***=[ID]&"-"&[Code INSEE de la commune]***

***=CONCATENATE([ID],"-",[Code INSEE de la commune])***

***=CONCATENATE([ID];"-";[Code INSEE de la commune])***
But it doesn't work...

Thanks a lot if you can help me !
[A screenshoot of my sharepoint list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urHpQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using SharePoint's auto generated ID in formula can be unreliable. To achieve what you want, you can create a very simple SharePoint workflow that runs upon `Item Creation`. What workflow will do is to simply take the `ID` and `Postal Code` from current item, compose the require string and update desired column of current item. 
Example Flow snapshot:
[image]

Updated Item:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is a good idea, but in fact it's work if i use a single text column to do that with MS FLOW, but it doesn't work if i try to do that with the TITLE COLUMN... i don't understand why

Comment: thats strange. lemme try that

Comment: it's working for me, check the updated answer for flow example